# Local SQL connection timeout

Tags: sql

For the past couple of weeks at exactly 6 AM all connection to the DB are stopped.  I assumed this was a network error, but the error happens when using management studio on the machine where the DB is installed, i.e. NO NETWORK it is the local SQL. The error is connection timeout.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could cause this?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: You've been infected by the 6AM DB Ghost... call for an exorcism

Comment: More seriously, just because a DB is local does not mean the network stack is not used... if something happens to reset all network connections at 6 am it could still cause a local db to lose an existing connection.  Even local it sill uses TCP/IP.  Try disconnecting your machine from your network and seeing if it happens then.  Nothing external could cause a reset at any network layer then.

Comment: that is going to be hard to do, as it is a virtual machine and I am able to RDP into the machine to see that I can't connect localy

Comment: @MtnManChris - Maybe the VMs are restarted at 6 AM by your hosting system.